# yii-auth set theme

Tags: authentication, layout, module, yii, themes

I want use in yii-auth module my layout. But in that layout i have

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>
```

because i need load some css files and images. Module yii-auth doesnt have theme set, so i get error because theme "panel" is not set.

Yii-auth settings let me set only layout, not theme.

I can easy set this by modify yii-auth module, but then i have to remember about this while yii-auth update. Its dirty :)

The question is: How can i change theme for yii-auth without tuching modules/auth folder?

Edit:
My default config is other then "panel". I cant set 'theme'=>'panel' in config/main.php.

Answer (score 0):

As you can define a custom layout for the module you can do this (eg. file `views/layouts/panel.php`):

```
<?php Yii::app()->theme = 'panel'; ?>
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__).'/main.php') ?>
```

Which will set another theme and then just use the main layout file.
In your config you should set `//layouts/panel` as the default layout for your auth module.

You can also do this one a per file/view bases, see [this file](https://github.com/schmunk42/p3bootstrap/blob/9f0df57e2f97639ada612ce724db6408149b4f13/views/rights/default/index.php) for a sample implementation.

[UPDATE]

Please have a look at https://github.com/schmunk42/multi-theme
You can define a theme per controller route.

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting

```
    'appLayout' => 'webroot.themes.bootstrap.views.layouts.main', // the layout used by bootstrap theme.
```

in /config/main.php did the trick

```
 'auth' => array(
            'strictMode' => true, // when enabled authorization items cannot be assigned children of the same type.
            'userClass' => 'User', // the name of the user model class.
            'userIdColumn' => 'id', // the name of the user id column.
            'userNameColumn' => 'username', // the name of the user name column.
            'defaultLayout' => 'application.views.layouts.main', // the layout used by the module.
            'appLayout' => 'webroot.themes.bootstrap.views.layouts.main', // the layout used by bootstrap theme.
            'viewDir' => null, // the path to view files to use with this module.
        ),
```